# Composer is very slow while downloading Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

can you help me please? I want to install Laravel via `composer create-project laravel/laravel` in to the `cms` directory but Composer downloads it very very slow. Can you help me with it how to boost it?

Here is my terminal:

```
saidalo@Saidalo-Yodgoroff:/var/www/html$ composer create-project laravel/laravel cms "5.1.*"
Installing laravel/laravel (v5.1.33)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.1.33)
    Downloading: 100%         

Created project in cms
> php -r "copy('.env.example', '.env');"
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v1.1.1)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing symfony/var-dumper (v2.7.11)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing symfony/translation (v2.7.11)
    Downloading: Connecting...
```

I don't know what to do!

Comment: What about internet connection?

Comment: run `composer diagnose` to check if there are connectivity problems on your device

Comment: Try `--prefer-dist` it might be a bit faster than pullung from source: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install

Comment: If you have xdebug installed it may slow composer down

Comment: @Peh It's unnecessary since this is the default option: *For stable versions Composer will use the `dist` by default*

Comment: Sometimes it can take time simply because the connection to GitHub is slow. Is it always slow? Have you tried at another hour of the day?

Comment: Yes, it is. Even on higher internet speeds, it takes 1-2min.

Comment: @Vucko 1 or 2 mins is okay i believe. I have experienced 1 hour for installing Laravel dependencies (T.T)

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
composer config --global repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org
```

to force https

Comment: That fixed it! Composer used http for connecting and that took very long for downloads.

Answer (score 1):

There is a package to speed up your composer. It may be useful

1. Disable Xdebug
   Turn it off and be happy.
2. Use Prestissimo
   is a global Composer plugin that installs dependencies in parallel. It is crazy fast. It’s worth noting that Prestissimo requires cURL, which may not work behind certain firewalls or proxies. I haven’t run into any issues at all personally.

Source: [composer speed up from laravel](http://jackmcdade.com/blog/tired-of-waiting)

Comment: Afaik, composer displays a warning if xdebug is in use, which is not the given case.

Answer (score 0):

Try [hirak/prestissimo](https://github.com/hirak/prestissimo) Composer plug-in. It will drastically reduce dependency installation process of any large project.

Answer (score 0):

I disabled IPv6 on my network card it seems to have fixed it. Image below of what I unchecked, hope that helps.

[Disable IPv6 Img Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkspa.png)