# Is using the command "composer create-project laravel/laravel [name of my project]" the correct way of creating a new Laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

When creating a Laravel project I use the command **"composer create-project laravel/laravel [name of my project]"**. It takes more than 5 minutes to create and also installs Laravel. Is this the correct way of creating a new Laravel Project?

Comment: Yes, this is the correct one with composer.

Comment: Have you installed laravel via composer before creating new project ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To create a new Laravel Project via composer we need to install laravel first. Below command is used to download and install laravel using composer.

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

Once Laravel get installed on your pc `larevel new` command will create a fresh Laravel installation in the directory you specify.

```
laravel new Project_name
```

Also you can create new laravel project via composer as well. (I Used to create via Composer). You can run the below command in your terminal to create new laravel project.

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel project_name
```

It will take couple of minitues to create the project. Once it done go the the project directory and run the command `php artisan serve` to start the development server at `http://localhost:8000:`

Refer Laravel [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to install Laravel. One of the simplest ways would be to install through composer with the command:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel MyAppName
// -- flag means optional
```

But...

It depends on your internet speed.

Even on higher internet speeds, it takes 1-2 mins

Seems [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36832860/composer-is-very-slow-while-downloading-laravel)